# matlab contourf for matrix-vector-function

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do contour-plots of functions of the form x^TAx-b^Tx where $x$ is a 2-dimensional vector and A a 2x2-matrix. I tried plotting with the following code:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5, -5:0.1:5);
z = x'*A*x - b'*x;
contourf(x,y,z);
```

Obviously this did not work as there's some dimension problem with this. But how can I do this kind of contour-plot then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The x in the calculation of z is a vector of x and y coordinate of a point, not the matrix of x coordinates, as you have used. This code gets the x and y coordinates of each point, calculates z at that point then puts it back into a matrix of the correct size.

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(-5:0.1:5, -5:0.1:5);
X=[x(:)';y(:)'];
for i=1:length(X)       
    z(i) = X(:,i)'*A*X(:,i) - b*X(:,i);
end
z=reshape(z,size(x));
contourf(x,y,z);
```